# How to delete a file using git command line interface when it says permission denied on deleting?

Tags: git, git-bash

I am learning git from a youtube tutorial, I am unable to delete a file. When I am giving this command, where names.txt is file name, I see this:

```
$ rm -rf names.txt
rm: cannot remove 'names.txt': Permission denied"
```

```
samiksha@Kitty MINGW64 ~/Desktop/gitt (master)
$ git add .
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in names.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory

samiksha@Kitty MINGW64 ~/Desktop/gitt (master)
$ git commit -m "adding new files"
[master f1f061e] adding new files
 1 file changed, 12 insertions(+)

samiksha@Kitty MINGW64 ~/Desktop/gitt (master)
$ git log
commit f1f061eafb856a25ae5521482cee25f5e7ff1aeb (HEAD -> master)
Author: Mi-kio <something34@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Feb 18 14:59:04 2022 +0530


    adding new files

commit bc5b891ef1476ecfbbde57d1f96063c75f58b0c8
Author: Mi-kio <something34@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Feb 18 14:41:05 2022 +0530

    adding files

samiksha@Kitty MINGW64 ~/Desktop/gitt (master)
$ rm -rf names.txt
rm: cannot remove 'names.txt': Permission denied
```

The content of my names.txt is

```
akshi 
SAmiksha
Navanshi 
ANshuka
mansi
shuchi
anvi anaya
```

I am not able to delete it or any other file also in which I have not added any content.

Comment: You have a permissions error on your Windows setup. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/549908/chmod-not-working-in-mingw64-but-working-cygwin for instance. In general you should not put Git folders into your `Desktop` folder on Windows, though: that may be a cloud-synced folder.

Answer (score 1):

Run this on the *gitt (master)* directory:

```
samiksha@Kitty$ chmod 777 gitt
```

Then you can run the

```
$ rm -rf names.txt
```

This should give you the permission to modify any file in the whole directory.

Comment: `MINGW64` implies that this is Windows, using MinGW. [chmod does not work there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/549908/chmod-not-working-in-mingw64-but-working-cygwin).